# piping to createWriteStream to browser

Tags: javascript, browser, salesforce

I am using a library that pipes a blob to file. Though I tried many ways, I am unable to use this functionality on browser, the code for node is:

```
var fout = fs.createWriteStream('./path/to/document'); // output stream to file
conn.sobject('Document').record(documentId).blob('Body').pipe(fout)
```

I want to do this on a browser, and prefer the blob to be in a blob variable, so I can run `urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob)`